# mongodb update multiple fields of the same row using json

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

i am using node.js mongodb native driver.

Let's say I have a mongodb collection called tasks , each task looks like

```
{date:'29th jan', desc:'xxx', status:'incomplete'}
```

from user input I get a JSON object 'newData' of the form

```
{desc:'yyy',status:'complete'}
```

the way I am updating my mongodb row with this newData is something like

```
db.tasks.update({_id:newData.id},{$set:{desc:newData.desc,status:newData.status}})
```

there are only two fields here, so using $set on each pair in newData is OK, but my question is can I update the row, without having to write $set on each pair in newData, just mentioning newData once. (obviously I will keep the pair keys in newData the same as the ones is mongodb row)

Comment: Only by changing your document structure to accept your newData object. You could copy the newData property values into locals, but it hardly seems woth it for your example. You could use the ([with]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement in JavaScript, but it won't be faster, and it isn't recommended or supported in JS strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

Because the field names match, you can directly use `newData` in your `$set` like this:

```
db.tasks.update({_id:newData.id}, {$set: newData})
```

However, if you don't validate which fields `newData` contains, this can add unwanted data to your task doc.